# How to draw HighChart XAxis dynamically

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am drawing a highchart as-

```
options.series.push({ name: this.SubCity, data: this.Data });
```

where data is an array for series data.

I also have an array for xAxis Categeries as-

```
 Categ['Jan-Mar', 'Apr-Jun', 'Jul-Sep', 'Oct-Dec']
```

my chart is drawing correctly but problem with the xAxis categories
is I don't know how to set categories dynamically .

for more clarity i am adding some code-

```
 var PriceTrend = JSON.parse(Data);
 var AvgRate = new Array();
 var Categories = new Array();

 $(PriceTrend).each(function (index)
        {
            MaxRate.push(this.Max);
            MinRate.push(this.Min);
            AvgRate.push((this.Max + this.Min) / 2);
            Categories.push(this.Quarter);
        });


        TrendData.push({ SeriesID: SeriesID, Data: AvgRate, Visible: true, SubCity: SubCity, Categ: Categories });

        DisplayTrend();


function DisplayTrend()
{
options.series = [];

$(TrendData).each(function (Index)
{
    if (this.Visible)
    {
        options.series.push({ name: this.SubCity, data: this.Data });
    }
});
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to use setCategories? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories()

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the [`Axis.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) method.

```
Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({categories:['some','new','categories']}, true);
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ruuL5/).

[image: animated x axis update]

Comment: And if you need to dynamically update the x-axis min and max (for example on a time-series chart where you want to show real-time data for a set period e.g. 1hr), you can use the `setExtremes` method on the xAxis - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes. Example - `Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes(newMin, newMax, true)`. (The `true` is 'redraw', and `newMin` and `newMax` must be numeric)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it since only fiew months.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis()
http://jsfiddle.net/wvaGt

```
chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
        id: 'rainfall-axis',
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall'
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#08F',
        opposite: true
    });
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',
        yAxis: 'rainfall-axis',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    });
```

Hope it will help someone.